# Pandas making a dataframe with a repeating column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having the two vectors below, I am trying to get the desired output without a for loop.

```
re = [1,2]
po = [1, 3, 5, 10, 20]
```

Desired output:

```
re  po
1   1
1   3
1   5
1   10
1   20
2   1
2   3
2   5
2   10
2   20
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.product` and the DataFrame constructor:

```
re = [1,2]
po = [1, 3, 5, 10, 20]

from itertools import product
df = pd.DataFrame(product(re, po), columns=['re', 'po'])
```

You can also use `pandas.MultiIndex.from_product` and transform `to_frame`:

```
re = [1,2]
po = [1, 3, 5, 10, 20]

df = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([re, po], names=['re', 'po']).to_frame(index=False)
```

Output:

```
   re  po
0   1   1
1   1   3
2   1   5
3   1  10
4   1  20
5   2   1
6   2   3
7   2   5
8   2  10
9   2  20
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections ;) (was typing from a phone)

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply each list by the length of the other and pass it to `pd.DataFrame`:

```
out = pd.DataFrame([re*len(po), po*len(re)], index=['re','po']).T.sort_values(by=['re','po'])
```

Output:

```
   re  po
0   1   1
6   1   3
2   1   5
8   1  10
4   1  20
5   2   1
1   2   3
7   2   5
3   2  10
9   2  20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [merge function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to do a cross merge. To do this, you would make each vector a dataframe then merge them like this :

```
re = [1,2]
po = [1, 3, 5, 10, 20]
reDf = pd.DataFrame({"re":re})
po = pd.DataFrame({"po":po})
repo = re.merge(po,how="cross")
```

Or if you don't want to define new variables:

```
re = [1,2]
po = [1, 3, 5, 10, 20]
repo = pd.DataFrame({"re":re}).merge(pd.DataFrame({"po":po}), how="cross")
```

Output:

```
   re  po
   1   1
   1   3
   1   5
   1  10
   1  20
   2   1
   2   3
   2   5
   2  10
   2  20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension: `output = [[x,y] for x in re for y in po]`

Here's the full code.

```py
import pandas as pd

re = [1,2]
po = [1, 3, 5, 10, 20]

output = [[x,y] for x in re for y in po]

df = pd.DataFrame(output, columns = ['re', 'po'])

display(df)
```

Output:

```py
   re  po
0   1   1
1   1   3
2   1   5
3   1  10
4   1  20
5   2   1
6   2   3
7   2   5
8   2  10
9   2  20
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is with the [expand_grid](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.expand_grid.expand_grid) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) which is pretty fast:

```py
#pip install pyjanitor
import janitor as jn

others = {'re':re, 'po':po}
jn.expand_grid(others = others).droplevel(1,1)
 
   re  po
0   1   1
1   1   3
2   1   5
3   1  10
4   1  20
5   2   1
6   2   3
7   2   5
8   2  10
9   2  20
```